# webbrowser control LoadCompleted Event Not Firing when Using NavigateToString Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight

I am working in Silverlight 5 webbrowser control to show the Contents. I have Used this Code Which Worked Fine For me.

Xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtUri" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
<Button x:Name="btnGo" Grid.Column="1" Content="Go" Click="OnGo" Margin="5" />
<WebBrowser LoadCompleted="browserControl_LoadCompleted"  ScriptNotify="browserControl_ScriptNotify" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" x:Name="browserControl" />
```

.CS

```
private void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("called");
    }

    private void browserControl_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("called");
        btnGo.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private void OnGo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         btnGo.IsEnabled = false;
         browserControl.Navigate(new Uri(txtUri.Text, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    }

    private void browserControl_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
        }
    }
```

It Disable the Button And Search For TextBox entered URI but When i change the OnGo Method

```
private void OnGo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         btnGo.IsEnabled = false;
         browserControl.NavigateToString("<html>   <head><title>Sample Readme File</title><script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> function GetSelectedText() {window.external.notify('Text to show in Message box');}</script></head>   <body>    <a onclick='GetSelectedText()'>Click Me</a>  <p>Sample Readme Content</p>   </body></html>");
    }
```

And Add the ScriptNotify Event Handler

```
void webBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Value);
        }
    }
```

Then webBrowser_LoadCompleted event does not Triggered.

What is the difference behind these two.

Please Help!

Comment: Top-level navigation occurs when the Source property is set or Navigate is called or If an error occurs, such as the content cannot be found. These are the Remarks from Msdn. I hope this function cannot be used but I require a Method which when call when all the Html loaded into the webbrowser control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [webbrowser control LoadCompleted Event Not Firing when Using NavigateToString Silverlight 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039710/webbrowser-control-loadcompleted-event-not-firing-when-using-navigatetostring-si)